# jQuery modal-dialog conflict with html() and return false;

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have an org chart using slickmap.css which I modified with toggle show/hide. It's all working fine but now I need to add a modal dialog window on click and display info form the a tag.

I managed to do this but had to add a return false to prevent the toggle close action from happening. Now when I display the info it completely removes the a tag from the page. I think when I add html(this), it ignores the return false at the end.

Please can anyone help me make these two functions work together.

Here is the code I am using to call the modal-dialog, sorry I havent posted a fiddle but I think this is where the problem lies

```
$('#samplelink').click(function(){
  $('#modal_window').dialog('open').html(this);
  return false;
}); //end click handler
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `.html(this)`? Are you looking for `.html($(this).html())`?

Comment: Thanks yes, that worked. Please can you tell me why that worked. Also post it as an answer and I'll accept, cheers

Comment: Actually I can see why that worked and mine only half worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass `this` to the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

Since that code lies inside an event handler, `this` will be the DOM element handling the event (`click` in our case). `html()` can only take a string or a function argument.

If your goal is to fill the dialog with the contents of `#samplelink`, you should call `html()`  on the current element without arguments, then call `html()` on the dialog with the resulting string:

```
$("#samplelink").click(function() {
    $("#modal_window").dialog("open").html($(this).html());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I had no idea that the assigned value of "this" could change if it is inside an event handler. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('#samplelink').click(function(){
  $('#modal_window').dialog('open').html($(this).html());
  return false;
}); //end click handler
```

Where `$(this).html()` contains valid HTML code.

You could try rapidly

```
$('#samplelink').click(function(){
  $('#modal_window').dialog('open').html('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
  return false;
}); //end click handler
```

Comment: Thanks David that was the correct answer, Frederic had answered it before in the comments, that's why I chose his, thanks